# Reading A Variable Set On Another Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm building a windows phone app, and I need a settings page. I figured out how to set the settings but now I need to know how to read them from the main page.

So from MainPage.xaml.cs I need to check if ExitAlert is true or false on Settings.cs, and I can't figure out how. I'm sure it's something simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in windows temporary settings (For particular instance) are stored in the  "PhoneApplicationService.Current.State" 
and the  Permanent settings will be stored in the "System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings"

As per your query

you can store the value in the settings page as follows

```
if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Contains("ExitAlert"))
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ExitAlert"] = value;
else
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add("ExitAlert", value);
```

and you can access the value from the main page as follows

```
if(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Contains("ExitAlert"))
   value = (bool)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ExitAlert"];

if(value == true)
   Messagebox.Show("Exit alert is set");
```

Hope it solve your issue.

Comment: Using isolated storage will share the value across all instances of the application. I think the question is asking only to share the value across pages within a single application instance. The value from a previous invocation of the application should not be available to a new invocation. If that's the case, I suggest using application resources (see my answer) instead, since they are scoped to an application instance.

Comment: I've already got it set up to store it in isolated storage, so will the example of accessing the value still work?

Comment: @Rev, yes you can use isolated storage for sharing a value across pages within an application. I'd raise two concerns. First, using isolated storage is going to be slower access than using application resources. Second, you'll need to take care to ensure that values in isolated storage from a previous execution of the app do not create any unwanted situations in a new execution of the app. Neither of these are insurmountable. So it can be made to work with a little care, it is just not optimal for your situation.

Comment: @Rev, i agree with the Mr. visual Stuart that isolated storage takes more time , which impacts your application performance, so its better to use the PhoneApplicationService.Current.State for the temporary storing of settings.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing a value across pages within an application instance, add the value to the application resources in the producing page, and get the value from the resource in another.

Here are some helper methods that I use frequently, which illustrate how to use the application resources.

```
public static T GetResource<T>( object key ) where T : class
{
  return Application.Current.Resources[ key ] as T;
}

public static T GetResourceValueType<T>( object key ) where T : struct
{
  object value = Application.Current.Resources[ key ];
  return (value != null)
    ? (T)value
    : new T();
}

public static void SetResource( object key, object resource )
{
  if ( Application.Current.Resources.Contains( key ) )
    Application.Current.Resources.Remove( key );

  Application.Current.Resources.Add( key, resource );
}
```

Note that SetResource works around the fact that you cannot change the value of an application resource once it is set, so it removes the old resource and then adds a new one. The difference between GetResource and GetResourceValueType is whether the the type is a CLR resource type (i.e., a class) or a CLR value type (i.e., a struct such as int or bool).

For your example, you would use them like this:

```
bool exitAlert_Page1 = true;
SetResource( "ExitAlert", exitAlert );

// elsewhere...
bool exitAlert_Page2 = GetResourceValueType<bool>( "ExitAlert" );
```

I usually use these helper methods to implement a C# property's get and set methodsso that the 'key' value used is limited to the property definition.

*Update: Since this has come up before, I wrapped this up, with a few small improvements and downloadable code, in a blog post http://www.visualstuart.net/blog2/2011/11/sharing-values-across-wp7-pages/ . Enjoy!*